# How to retrieve Route parameters in Controller __construct()

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to pull two parameters into my Controller's *__construct()* method, but I keep getting the  following debug

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Router::parameters()

What I'm specifically trying to do is.

- Pull the **"portal"** and **"issue"** parameters into my *__construct* and set the **$currentPortal** and **$currentIssue** variables in my class *(protected variables)*
- Use those two protected vars when I please in different Controller actions

Down below you'll find my *__construct()* method

```
protected $portals, $issues, $currentPortal, $currentIssue;

public function __construct(\App\Entities\Portal $portals, \App\Entities\Issue $issues){
    $this->portals = $portals;
    $this->issues = $issues;

    dd(\Route::parameters());

    if($portal = \Route::getParameter('portal'))
        $this->currentPortal = $this->portals->findBySlug($portal);

    if($issue = \Route::getParameter('issue'))
        $this->currentIssue = $this->issues->findByKey($issue);
}
```

As you can notice, I'm using **dd()** as a debug helper in order to see if the current Route parameters and being pulled.

There's no issue in the router.php definitions, as I have already tested them before trying to implement this handy "hack" to pull the current objects.

Any help in order to get the current Route params?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah, I figured it out just after posting this question!

I'm leaving the answer in case anyone is having the same issue as I was..

**You need to pull the current() route** before appending any other requests, so in my case, I should've done

> Route::current()->getParameter('MY PARAM NAME')

That should be it